# Checkbox checked based on Databased value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a dynamic checkbox. All the checkbox has dynamic ID as shown in code below. This checkbox is bind using **"TABLE1"**.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="22" name="chkRoles" value="RecordOne">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="22" name="chkRoles" value="Recordtwo">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="19" name="chkRoles" value="Recordthree">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="30" name="chkRoles" value="RecordFour">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="35" name="chkRoles" value="RecordFive">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="25" name="chkRoles" value="RecordSix">
```

I am fetching the data from other TABLE, let's say **TABLE2**. Which contain value19,22,25.

```
var sectionLevelOne = "19,22,25";
var levelArrayOne = sectionLevelOne.split(",");
$.each(levelArrayOne, function (index, value){
       $("chkRoles_"+id).prop("checked",true);
});
```

I want to checked those CHECKBOX whose ID is "19,22,25".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you have multiple elements with the same `id`. This is invalid as `id` attributes *have* to be unique. If you cannot achieve that, use `data-id` to store custom data on the element.

That aside, your code is not building a valid `id` selector based on the HTML you've shown as `chkRoles` is the *class*, not the `id`. You can also simplify the logic. Try this:

```js
"19,22,25".split(',').forEach(id => {
  $(`[data-id="${id}"]`).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="22" name="chkRoles" value="RecordOne">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="22" name="chkRoles" value="Recordtwo">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="19" name="chkRoles" value="Recordthree">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="30" name="chkRoles" value="RecordFour">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="35" name="chkRoles" value="RecordFive">
<input type="checkbox" class="level-one" data-id="25" name="chkRoles" value="RecordSix">
```

Comment: yes sir you right related `ID`. I am fresher so making silly mistake. :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help